# Build.gradle gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I bought a book called Pivotal Certified Professional Spring Developer Exam and the source code came with Gradle.

Following instructions I installed Gradle. The version I got was 4.2.1 and the book was 2.11 by the time it was published.

I tried both command line and via IDEA IntelliJ but in both I got the same error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/gradle/scan/plugin/internal/b/j/b 
>       at com.gradle.scan.plugin.internal.b.j.a.a(SourceFile:1016)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please include the project structure and the specific build.gradle?

Answer (score 2):

The answer turned out to be quite simple. Just update the com.gradle.build-scan version to 1.9 and you're set.